# how to keep track of play and pause events on an embedded blackberry media player on a website?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, blackberry

I'm using an embedded media player on my website to allow blackberry users to listen to audio without having to download it. (I'm testing this on blackberry bold 9700 and so any cool html5, flash or embed tags wont work) The reason I have it embedded is because I want to be able to keep track of a users listening time.

Basically what I want is to be able to know when a user clicks play or pause. How do I gain control of these buttons? possibly using some jquery?

This is my code for the player:

```
<object data="myfilepathHere" type="audio/mpeg">embedded track isnt working!</object>
```

This is the site I used as a reference:
http://devblog.blackberry.com/2009/08/blackberry-browser-embedded-media-content-automatic-playback-how-to/

I can get the two buttons play/pause and stop to show up (and it looks just like it does in the link I've provided) on the blackberry and the track to play so if I can get this to work that would be just dandy. thanks! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, I spent some time trying some ideas out and I'm pretty certain it's not possible to track or listen to any events on the Object. You really need the Audio tag on BBOS 6.0 and higher. If you were doing a WebWorks app instead of a website we have an API that would help (https://developer.blackberry.com/html5/apis/blackberry.audio.player.html).

Supporting 6.0+ is not that bad. You may find that the majority of people who visit your site have that version or higher.